# Получение Digital Signature с помощью Eliptic Curve алгоритма

Tags: криптография, openssl

Вообщем пытаюсь получить сигнатуру сообщения с помощью элиптического ключа, но в результате при каждом запуске получаю разные значения.

- Создание ключа:

```bsh
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem
```

- Получение сигнатуры сообщения из файла `data` в base64

```bsh
cat data | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign key.pem -binary | openssl base64
```

В результате двух последовательных запусков получаю два разных ответа, к примеру:

```
MEUCIQC3eEBbeU83Fd/fdzfnUi1oe5We5NildCmVjUCkIpErPQIgeHVVoVHP4z6C
KhZPmAVIz/MX6vTgCCSd3t7QnZmHmMw=
```

```
MEYCIQC9zmlo2W/MN2CTx92rjviS3PpG6lW2ouTbARQCuL9gdwIhAJ+MoDmRiiHp
YqFVkkc9PM0v1e5VyMYdL9EIXKORqqh1
```

Не понимаю почем так? Или использую неверный вызов для получения сигнатуры? Также я получал сигнатуру с помощью rsa ключей, для элептических может по-другому?

Comment: с виду с командами всё в порядке... почти наверняка перед подписью он просто данные случайным числом подсаливает... действительно так ли это и, возможно ли это отключить я утверждать не решусь..

Answer (score 1):

А вы проверьте правильность подписи ;)

Сначала сгенерируем открытый ключ:

```
openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -out public.pem
```

Немного модифицируем вашу команду, добавим сохранение подписи в файл.

```
cat data | openssl dgst -sha256 -sign key.pem -binary | tee sign.bin | openssl base64
```

Подпись сохранена в файле `sign.bin`. Теперь проверим:

```
cat data | openssl dgst -verify public.pem -signature sign.bin
```

Результат: `Verified OK`

Несмотря на то, что подписи каждый раз получаются разными, они успешно верифицируются. Почему же подписи каждый раз получаются разными. Взгляните на [описание алгоритма в википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Signature_generation_algorithm), шаги 3 и 4:

> 3. Select a cryptographically secure random integer k from [1,n-1]

> 4. Calculate the curve point (x1,y1) = k x G

В переводе на русский - *возьмите **произвольную** точку в группе точек эллиптической кривой*...

Точка каждый раз выбирается новая, отсюда и разнобой в подписи.